# The number of coffee shops in a particular county t years after the coffee shop reform act is given by

Tags: calculus

The number of coffee shops in a particular county t years after the coffee shop reform act is given by

$S(t) = (2t+1)^5$  shops

$a)$ At what rate is the number of shops changing $1$ year after the Coffee shop reform act?

Not sure where to start with this. Missed class on rate of change, if you could help me get started, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Find $\frac{dS}{dt} =10(2t+1)^4$, Thus the rate by which the number of shops change 1 year later is $\frac{dS}{dt}|_{t=1} =10(2\times 1+1)^4 = 810$

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the derivative of $S(t)$, called $S'(t)$. Use the power rule to get $S'(t)=5\cdot 2(2t+1)^4$ and plug in $t=1$.